# Form submit doesn't work, just refreshes page

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the submit button, the data does not go to opiekunowie.php, instead the page only refreshes. I don't know why.

```html
<form id="opiekunform" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="formparent">
        <div class="formicon">
            <img style="width: 1.5vw; height: 1.5vw; margin-top: 0.9vw;" src="ikonki/email.svg">
        </div>
        <input id="opiekuninput" type="text" name="opiekun" placeholder="E-mail"/>
        <div class="error"></div>
        <div class="errorarrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="formparent">
        <input id="opiekunx" type="submit" value="Gotowe!" class="git" />
        <div class="error"></div>
        <div class="errorarrow"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The Javascript:

```js
var opiekunx = document.getElementById("opiekunx");
opiekunx.addEventListener("click", function eee()
{
    //if (document.getElementById("opiekuninput").value = "")
    //    document.getElementById("opiekuninput").value = "brak";

    document.getElementById("opiekunform").setAttribute("action", "opiekunowie.php");
    document.getElementById("opiekunform").submit();
}
, false);
```

Comment: Why is the action no set by default? Why do you have it bound to the click of a form and not the submit event?

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery and php? You don't seem to be using either...

Comment: Change the form tag like this: `<form action="opiekunowie.php" ...>`. The three dots ... should be replaced with the already existing attributes. Remove the JavaScript code, it isn't needed to send the form.

Comment: It would be also good if you remove the tags `php`, `jquery` and `css`, as @MattGibson already mentioned the first two. The quality of SO relies on meaningfully tagged questions.

Comment: I've edited the post to remove the irrelevant tags, etc. Note that your original post says you are submitting to opiekunowie.php, however you have not included that here. If the top block of code is that, fine, but it contains no PHP code that would handle a form, so a refresh is exactly what I'd expect to happen (what else would happen?).

Comment: Thanks now it is working. In the ast I had problem with submit and adding action by javasript solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not defining action attribute in html

Change this line of html

```
<form id="opiekunform" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

With this line

```
<form id="opiekunform" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="opiekunowie.php">
```

For more on action attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: Can you please provide more information or some explanation. The OP should learn something, not copy and paste code without understanding.